# Disable selected options between 5 selectlists with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 selectboxes in my HTML page and I'm trying to disable all the options in the other selectboxes that are already selected, they also have to be re-enabled when they are deselected.

So far I came to this result: [Click here for JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhngx/5/)

Using this JQuery

```
$('.poli').on('keyup change', function () {
$(this)
    .siblings('select')
    .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
    .attr('disabled', true)
    .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

This however, doesn't work too well, It only selects and disables 1 option at the time...

Any solutions?

Comment: Well, first off, you don't want to do this: `.siblings().removeAttr('disabled');` as that means that only the *LAST* select is disabled in all other select boxes. You want to enable (removeAttr('disabled')) when none of the selects have that choice. So you need to iterate (.each()) over all the selects and check if any have selected a particular option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

### DEMO

```
$('.poli').on('keyup change', function () {
    var selectedValues = $('.poli').find('option:selected').map(function () {
        return this.value ? this.value : null;
    });
    $('.poli').filter(function () {
        return !this.value
    }).find('option').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', ~$.inArray(this.value, selectedValues));
    });
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the tilde before `$.inArray` do? I've never seen that before

Comment: @billyonecan That's to convert `-1` to 0, using it as falsy result

Comment: That's neat. I'm going to have to start using that from now on :p

Comment: @billyonecan Be aware, some boss don't like it, finding it unreadable, which is not wrong in some way :)

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It works good. There is only one thing that should be diffrent... Now the selectlist in which you have chosen a name, also disables that option which results in returning a NULL value after submitting the form :f, is there any solution to this?

Comment: You should filter the selection, see updated answer if it fits your needs http://jsfiddle.net/xhngx/21/

Answer (score 4):

I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhngx/11/). You need to keep track of the selected options and disable those in the other select boxes:

```
$('.poli').on('keyup change', function () {
    var selected = [];
    $(".poli option:selected").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") 
            selected.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(".poli:not(this) option").each(function () {
        if (selected.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) 
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        else 
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This cleans up the disable; I'm working on the enabling code will post in a minute:

```
$('select').change( function () {
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('select').children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh well, the others posted the solution -- iterate and check which options are chosen nowhere else.